IDE complaining on @Async for @Scheduled method
I defined this scheduled task:
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class DoWork {
   
    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "xxxxxxxx")
    public void foo(){
    }
}

I am getting warning in IDE on @Async:

Remove this "@Async" annotation from this method.

I need to execute this method in background thread, every x minutes.
I don't need pool of threads, only 1 additional thread for this task.
Expecting not to see the warning.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482865/using-scheduled-and-async-together

none of the answers there were accepted, and all different

You don't need @Async there. By default, methods annotated with @Scheduled in Spring are not executed in the main thread but in a thread managed by Spring's task scheduler, typically using a single-threaded task executor - you can verify it by logging the thread's name using 'Thread.currentThread().getName()'. Also, I think it's cleaner to use @Component instead of @Configuration since this is not a configuration class.
Also if you wanna configure a threadpool with a single thread for it, you can use ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

do I have to explicitly set ThreadPoolTaskScheduler? can I just set spring.task.scheduling.pool.size?

In Spring Boot it is possible to set it via application.properties. You can use 'spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=?'
