# Spring @Scheduled in multiple classes, but scheduler returns to a single class

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks

I Have a multiple classes (1,2,3,4) with @Scheduled where i have different times specified for each task/Process to run. Here I have created config class with all the schedulers beans in the config but, every time it returns the call to a single class 1.

Is there anything i need to be added in the config class? Than the below one

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.something.too.foo")
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public MyTask1 myTask1(){
    return new MyTask1();
    }
    @Bean
    public MyTask2 myTask2(){
    return new MyTask2();
    }
    @Bean
    public MyTask3 myTask()3{
    return new MyTask3();
    }
    @Bean
    public MyTask4 myTask()4{
    return new MyTask4();
    }
```

Not sure what to be added to process all the Tasks in parallel processing. Help is very much Appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796651/what-is-the-default-scheduler-pool-size-in-spring-boot

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344801/spring-scheduler-parallel-running